# Sequence of Raku program compilation and execution (maybe nested compile phases?)

Tags: compilation, raku, compile-time, rakudo

The following program correctly fails to compile:

```
sub f(Int $a) { my Str $b = $a }
say f 42;
say f 'foo';
```

Specifically, line 3 causes a compilation error (with a `===SORRY!===` error message); this error occurs before line 2 is executed, so the type mismatch within &f is never reached.

But when, specifically, does this error occur?  I thought it occurred during the CHECK [phase](https://docs.raku.org/language/phasers), but was surprised to notice that `raku -c` does not generate a compile error; it reports `Syntax OK`.

To dig into this a bit more, I added logging code to the snippet above:

```
BEGIN note 'begin';
CHECK note 'check';
INIT  note 'init';
END   note 'end';

sub f(Int $a) { my Str $b = $a }
say f 42;
say f 'foo';
```

Running this revised code with `raku -c` prints "begin\n check\n Syntax OK"; running it with `raku` prints "begin\n check\n ===SORRY!===" (and the rest of the error message).

If I remove the `say f 'foo'` line (and thus the compile error), `raku -c` still prints "begin\n check\n Syntax OK" but `raku` prints "begin\n check\n init\n Type check failed… \n end" (again omitting the body of the error message).

What's going on here?  Does the compile error that generated the `===SORRY!===` occur some time *between* CHECK and INIT (is there any such time?)?  Or does `raku -c` not actually "run BEGIN and CHECK blocks" as `raku --help` indicates?  Or something else?

Relatedly: how, if at all, is any of this connected to the idea of "nested compile times"?  Does the execution of this code involve any nested compile times, or does that only occur when using modules?  Is there any way to note/log separate compile phases (maybe with correctly placed BEGIN blocks?) or is that something that isn't exposed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SORRY message is a side-effect of the static optimizer.  Observe the difference in behaviour between:

```
$ raku -e 'sub foo(Int $a) { }; foo "foo"'
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling -e
Calling foo(Str) will never work with declared signature (Int $a)
```

and:

```
$ raku --optimize=off -e 'sub foo(Int $a) { }; foo "foo"'
Type check failed in binding to parameter '$a'; expected Int but got Str ("foo")
  in sub foo at -e line 1
```

which happens somewhere between `CHECK` and `INIT` time, unless it has been disabled.  Note that disabling the static optimizer makes it a runtime error.

Comment: Interesting, thanks!  In case anyone else is curious, that's true of **that** SORRY message, but not all SORRY messages.  If we introduce a syntax error, (e.g. `raku --optimize=off -e 'sb foo(Int $a) { }; foo "foo"`), we can still get a SORRY error without the optimizer.

Comment: Indeed.  The SORRY means it's an error that occurred during compilation.  Well, mor precisely perhaps: before the INIT phaser runs.

Comment: It's also to be expected that the new compiler frontend currently in development will re-order and generally shift around various bits of error handling, since there's more than one reasonable way to structure a Raku compiler. I rather suspect the type errors in the question that aren't currently in `-c` will probably end up there as a side-effect of the structural changes.